# Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I faced with some issue

> %3|1622567567.487|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: kafka:9092: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution (after 27431ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)

How to resolve that issue, any idea?
**The issue describes in the screenshot**

```
nkafka-console-app:
    build: 
      context: dotNet/examples/
      dockerfile: Src/KafkaConsoleApp/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - producer_topic=console_topic_test
      - consumer_topic=console_topic_test
      - kafka_endpoint=kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - kafka   
 zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1
    restart: always
    environment:
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
     ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"
     ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: "2000"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.2.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

```
var config = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = conf.kafka_endpoint, BatchSize = 100000, LingerMs = 100 };

var configConsumer = new ConsumerConfig
                {
                    BootstrapServers = kafkaEndpoint,
                    EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
                    EnableAutoCommit = true,
                    AutoCommitIntervalMs = 10000,
                    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
                    GroupId = "group.id"
                };
```

[image]

[image]

Zookeeper logs
[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you start the containers?

Comment: In which container is your consumer placed?

Comment: I use docker-compose all images placed in one container

Comment: I don't see a console app container in your docker-compose file?

Comment: I forgot to add in descriptions. I have added just

Comment: if you are running your app on Windows and trying to connect to Kafka running in the container you need to add "kafka" to your hosts file. Otherwise, you can use ` localhost:9092` as a hostname

Answer (score 0):

In your image, the broker died because it couldn't resolve `zookeeper:2181`. Therefore, your app will fail to resolve `kafka:9092` because the broker isn't running .

You should run `docker-compose logs zookeeper` to verify that it started okay.

Comment: okay, but why zookeeper died?  What configuration I have to add ?

Comment: Also, `depends_on` doesn't ensure the services actually start _successfully_, only that the containers start in-order. I generally suggest running `docker-compose up -d zookeeper kafka` then wait a minute before starting your own app

Comment: I have just added logs, look plz screenshot

Comment: I just tried to get new logs but now docker-compose logs zookeeper not responding. Docker crashed

Comment: Seems to be working, although, there are a lot of exceptions

Comment: I assume you're on Windows? You need to increase the Docker memory to at least 4GB

Comment: I defined Memory: 5.00 GB

Answer (score -1):

When I used `docker stats` I notice that ms server takes a lot of memory. It was the root of my issue